# How do I make a custom WordPress admin menu icon?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress plugin and I'd like to put a custom icon in the main wordpress admin menu.

I've seen other plugins do this, the icons are grey. When you mouse over the item in the menu, the text and icon turn blue. If you are on that plugin's page, the text and icon are white.

I've created a custom icon as an svg (I'm new at svg though). I've set the fill to black, as I read about doing (somewhere on the internet), and added the menu icon like:

```
function admin_menu() {
            add_menu_page('MyPlugin Plugin admin', 'MyPlugin', 'manage_options', 'MyPlugin-plugin', null, 'data:image/svg+xml;base64, ' . base64_encode(file_get_contents(RPP_PLUGIN_DIR . 'assets/image/dashicon.svg')));
            add_submenu_page('MyPlugin-plugin', 'MyPlugin Plugin Settings', 'Settings', 'manage_options', 'MyPlugin-plugin', [$this, 'page_settings']);
            add_submenu_page('MyPlugin-plugin', 'MyPlugin Plugin Guide', 'Guide', 'manage_options', 'MyPlugin-plugin-guide', [$this, 'page_guide']);
        }
```

The icon appears in the admin menu as black, and doesn't change color when hovered nor selected.

I don't know if I have the code wrong, or if I need something other than a black shape in the svg file.

I haven't been able to find any documentation on how this works or what is required - can you help with an explanation and solution? What do I not understand? :)

Thanks,

Chris

edited - based on [the link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/#comment-5845) provided by O. Jones in the comments below, I tried simplifying the svg file, by simplifying in inkscape and then minimizing and removing everything that I could while keeping the svg working.

The icon still only displays in black though, wordpress is not doing the grey/blue/white overlay.

Here's the svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<path fill="black" d="M7.701 10.271l3.667-3.178c.405.617 1.366 1.274 1.417 1.866l-3.552 3.078-1.531-1.767zm.497 1.818l5.218-1.019c.092.622.711 1.556.485 1.991l-5.074.991-.629-1.963zm3.781-6.913l.875-3.294 1.578.424-.875 3.294-1.578-.424zm-6.55 6.267l1.167-5.11c.596.316 1.676.364 1.956.855l-1.13 4.951-1.992-.695zM3.353 7.026l.814-3.693c.518.283 1.896.013 1.741.73L5.17 7.41l-1.817-.384zm8.679 7.76l3.868 1.298c-.276.505-.298 1.52-.73 1.713l-3.728-1.251.591-1.76zM4.978 13.9l5.089 1.121c-.268.726-.218 1.949-.675 2.38l-4.945-1.089.531-2.411zm-3.208-.732l2.021-4.176c.589.389 1.732.58 1.989 1.087l-1.956 4.043-2.053-.954zm-.279 1.178l4.929-1.911c.189.782.933 1.81.767 2.435l-4.775 1.852-.921-2.376zm13.086-6.181h4.294v2.07h-4.294v-2.07z"/>
</svg>
```

I still don't understand what the:

"Then you will have to hardcode each style into the path, rather than using the tag. For each path, work out which classes apply to the path from the tag, and add the CSS from those classes into the path."

from the instructions on that link means, maybe that still needs to be done?

Comment: Presumably you have already read [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/#comment-5845) user-contributed note about making icon SVG objects. If not .... please do.

Comment: Thank you, I'm reading over that, I don't understand this, if you can help explain: "Then you will have to hardcode each style into the path, rather than using the tag. For each path, work out which classes apply to the path from the tag, and add the CSS from those classes into the path."

Comment: I added the svg to my question. The author of that note did say that fixing the code fixed the colors for him, so I think that's on the right track